# Check if a column exists in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

How do I check if a column exists in a table and add one if it doesn't exist?(I am using mysql)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns
WHERE Name = N'columnName' AND OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tableName'))
BEGIN
PRINT 'Your Column Exists'
END
```

This is a sample one.The results I got one from web are the older versions of mysql. I need the answer in the latest version (mysql server 2019 and above) .How do I solve it?

Comment: You have mysql in your tag, but both mysql and sql-server-2019 in your Question. This is very confusing. Also, if you're looking to find a SQL, why is node.js added as a tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below query

```sql
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name LIKE '%column_name%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access this kind of information from the `information_schema` database. It contains a `columns` table.

The `information_schema` database is part of ISO SQL, and implemented on all SQL servers :

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) ([COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html) table)
- [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) ([COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) table)
- [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) ([COLUMNS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html) table)

Here is a portable query :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'thedatabase'
  AND table_name = 'thetable'
  AND column_name = 'thecolumn';
```

Comment: I misread the docs, and thought the implementation was different between servers. Which would be awkward : the information_schema database is part of ISO SQL, and should be the same on all implementations. I fixed my answer.

Comment: SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE database_name = 'userInformation'
  AND table_name = 'Articles'
  AND column_name = 'article3';  //this is showing error 1054

Comment: I got the columns wrong in my initial answer : try `table_schema` instead of `database_name`